# AWS EKS Terminating Nodes Gracefully Without losing requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an issue with EKS where everytime we scale down whether manually or through autoscaling, it causes requests to be lost. We have around 200 requests per second so this is quite visible whenever it happens. We can see 524 response codes on cloudflare whenever this happens.

I have checked that my application server is handling requests gracefully. When I scale down my app server pods down, there is no issues. Same with our Istio. Scaling down ec2 nodes does cause this issue.

Is there something I need to do to enable graceful node terminations?

Comment: "How" do you scale down? Do you use the "Cluster Autoscaler"? Do you execute a command? Or how is the scaling managed?